# $\text{det}(A+B)$ is the sum of $\text{det}A$ and a linear combination of minors of $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinations, determinant

> Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices. Then $\text{det}(A+B)$ is the sum
>   of $\text{det}A$ and a linear combination of minors of $B$.

I want to show the above statement but get stuck. Anyone can give
a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about multi-linearity of determinant?

Comment: @Hamed No. What is that?

Comment: Careful: determinants are scalars, Scalars are automatically linear combinations of non-zero scalars. You should state your question more precisely.

Comment: The coefficients in the linear combination should be understood as polynomials in the entries of $A$, so that the assertion is still true even if the entries of $A$ and $B$ are $2n^2$ independent indeterminates. For a proof, one may consider $\det(tA+B)$ for instance.

Comment: It seems to me unwise to break the symmetry; I think it is more illuminating to say that $\det(A+B)$ is an integral sum of the product of each minor in $A$ times its complementary minor in $B$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use induction on the size of the matrix and, for the inductive step

Say $a_{i,j}, b_{i,j}$ are the elements of the matrices $A $ and $B $. Write $\det A+B $ with Laplace formula as

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (a_{1,i} + b_{1,i})\det M_i $$

Where $M_i$ is the submatrix you get by deleting the 1st row and $i $th column from $A+B $. Now rewrite $M_i $ as submatrices from $A, B $, and work your way through the sum, applying the induction hypothesis so that $\det A $ comes up, as well as some linear combination of minors of $B $.

Comment: Thank you so much. I followed up your hint and I got constant terms. Can we remove the constant terms?

Comment: @kayak what constant terms?